# Why has this questions comments been removed?

Tags: discussion

The question in mind is

[Measuring employee moods via an app to better engage with them, how viable?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/65671/measuring-employee-moods-via-an-app-to-better-engage-with-them-how-viable#comment179578_65671)

Please tell me why the comments have been removed.

Comment: FYI there are 28 currently deleted comments on that question (with 13 more there now for a total if 41)... Stack exchange is not a discussion board, by design.

Comment: Also I would encourage you to read through the help center page on comments - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment - it has a lot of good content about what the purpose of comments is, when comments are intended to be used, etc (however controversial it might be).

Comment: @enderland - *Criticisms which do not add anything constructive* This is subjective; If I was a moderator I would err on the side of leaving it in. Also seems that deleting comments from multiple people seems rather harsh

Comment: I also think there may be a cultural element to this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Our Comments Problem](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2748/our-comments-problem)

Answer (score 5):

Because comments are not for extended discussion.  They are for clarification and always intended to be ephemeral.  If they can stand on their own, then they should instead be posted as an answer.

Comment: Why was they just deleted and not just moved to chat? If they are just to be deleted why not have a note to say why this was the case

Comment: Almost half were flagged, there was no value in moving them to chat.

Comment: Who makes that judgement? What about the others that was not flagged?

Comment: The community moderators do.  It comes back to the understanding that comments are not intended to be permanent, and when a number have been flagged _by the community_, then we may remove them.

Comment: I would like to understand that a moderator can remove a comment even if was not flagged just because a comment before or after in the list has been. Also why cannot a note in that part of the interface be made to inform us lesser mortals why this is the case so we can learn?

Comment: Perhaps this is a discussion and therefore should be deleted or moved

Comment: Comments can be removed at a moderator's discretion.  If you wish to discuss a thread, you are welcome to create a chat room.  I would have thought that given your considerable experience with SE communities that you would already be aware of this :)

Comment: I have a more liberal outlook on life and think that any comment (free speech) should not be muted. Most of this will run out of steam. I think that the stuff that should be deleted is when it is offensive or personal. I am sorry that you think otherwise

Comment: @EdHeal: Ha! You'd be surprised. Many Internet discussions do not run out of steam. Try Reddit sometime.

Comment: Clearly comments get deleted only when a moderator gets tired of them. Most comments here are nothing more than extended discussion. And most of them are far from ephemeral. I have made a habit of deleting my comments once they get a few days old, so as not to contribute to the "comments problem" discussed here a while back. But most comments remain forever. If comments were truly intended to be ephemeral, they would become auto-deleted after a certain period of time.

Comment: @ed the purpose of SE never has been to give people a platform for "free speech" - it's a framework for question and answer. If you want a discussion board or forum, the SE suite of sites is really not a good fit philosophically. It has a fundamentally different purpose.

Comment: I just think that the moderator has been a bit heavy handed in this instance and just delete comments without comment. How can somebody learn? It is about free speech. Or is it about writing comments that you think that the moderator will be happy with? Why could the moderator not just move it to chat - or perhaps the moderator is more wiser that the rest of us lesser mortals.

Comment: @EdHeal: To some extent, it *is* about which comments make the moderators happy.http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199302/131956

Comment: Note that freedom of the press belongs to the man who owns and operates one. SE's site, SE's titles, as implemented by the admins. I agree that there is often good info in the comments, but we've been warned often enough that they are ephemeral and may be discarded any time they start getting out of control and/or at admins whim. If you can't deal with having your deathless prose cleans up, make it an answer

Comment: ... Though I do wish the admin cleanup process included summarizing as an answer more often.

Comment: @EdHeal - I think the Admins do the best they can. Sometimes it seems they don't delete enough, sometimes too often. But there are a LOT of comments posted, so I think that is to be expected. (And of course elections occur annually, so anyone can decide if they could do a better job and run for a position!) If it were my site, I'd leave all comments intact for a long period of time, then automatically delete them. But it's not my site - I just enjoy being here.

Comment: C/titles/rules/ in above. Autocorrect...

Answer (score 4):

Some observations from that question:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

That's a *lot* of noise. Keep in mind the purpose of comments is requesting clarification and improving the post.

What percentage of these comments do that (which are not obselete)? Nearly all are either:

- Commentary on the subject material

  - Quite a few are discussion related to the commentary
- Answers (post as answers... not comments!)

There are some which are geared towards improving the post. These are/were deleted when that was no longer relevant.

Your comment specifically "what a novel way of pissing off employees" is completely unhelpful. If you are interested in a site where you can try to make witty comments to try to get upvotes, go to Reddit or imgur.

Comments like that will continue to be deleted.

There will always be comments that get deleted by mistake, especially in the long comment threads like on this post. It is somewhat unavoidable until Stack Exchange programs replacements for us human moderators... However, yours was *not* one of those.

See [this link for guidance about comments](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> When should I comment? You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

If you disagree with this and desire Stack Exchange to allow more "discussion board" comments, I encourage you to open a suggestion on the main Stack Exchange [Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions).

Here are all the comments, for reference:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>